# rails save record to table before validating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have basically an invoice, and the post_status is nil and when its set to closed, users cant edit it anymore.

```
validate :post_status, :if => :opened?
def opened?
    if (post_status == 'Closed')
        errors.add(:base, "Already Closed")
        return false
    end
    return true
end
```

this is what i have but when I set to closed, it already starts validating it and so I cant really set it to closed. I want it to be able to set my post_status to closed, so then the next time I want to edit, I cant edit anymore because its already closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you. It uses [`validate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate) which lets you validate based on a method.

```
validate :opened_post_status

def opened_post_status
  saved_post_status = self.class.find(id).post_status

  if (saved_post_status == 'Closed')
    errors.add(:base, "Already Closed")
    false
  else
    true
  end  
end
```

Comment: it gives me error, it says you need to supply at least one validation

Comment: taking out the s in validates but when I set it to closed, the validation starts kicking in already which doesnt allow me to set it to close at all. because it already detects that so the table wont be saved as closed at all

Answer (score 0):

This is all because validation is calling on your update action. So better you set `status = 'Closed'` without any validation call.

For this you can use `update_column(name, value)` . update_column doesn't trigger any callback and you are done.

When you are updating column to `closed` in your controller use like below and you are done.

```
@object_to_close.update_column('status', 'Closed')
```

Comment: how would you do that if you are getting the value from forms? how do i pass that? @object_to_close.update_column(post_status: *what to put here* if the value is from forms?)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `post_status_was`, which is the value before update, to validate `Invoice` model.